# Import local class into project

Tags: c#, class, import, project

I have a class called Local in my project.
Is there a way to use import "Local" so i don't have to type the class name?
For example using

```
"Example()"
```

instead of

```
"Local.example()"?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but you can't do static import (like in Java) or class import (Python) in C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to directly call a method in another class within same project without using class instance then you can inherit that class. So you will be able to directly use public members of that class.

```
public class Local {

public void Example()
{
}
}

public class ChildClass : Local
{
Example();
}
```

Comment: public partial class Setup : Form inherits Form, is there a way to add another one?

Comment: You can't do multiple class inheritence.